# swiftui Array contents updated inside function closure but does not persist in other views

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

When fetching data from my database, I update an array from the json received inside the fetching function. While inside the function, the array stays updated, but when I try to access the array in a separate view, the array is empty.

the code that fetches the data and updates the "events" array looks like this:

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI

let apiUrl = "http://localhost:5000/"

class DataFetcher: ObservableObject {

    @Published var events: [eventdata] = []


   func fetchEvents(){

        events.removeAll()
        let url = NSMutableURLRequest(url: NSURL(string: apiUrl)! as URL)

        url.httpMethod = "GET"

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url as URLRequest) { data, response, err in
            if let err = err {
                print(err.localizedDescription)
                return
            }

            guard let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse else { return }
            if response.statusCode == 200 {
                guard let data = data else { return }
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    do{

                        self.events = try JSONDecoder().decode([eventdata].self, from: data)

                    //    print(self.events.last?.address)
                    }catch let err {
                        print("Error: \(err)")
                    }
                }
            } else {
                print("HTTPURLResponse code: \(response.statusCode)")
            }
        }.resume()

        //print(self.events.last?.address)
    }

}
```

The view that calls this function looks like this:

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI



struct CreateEventButton: View {
    @ObservedObject var request = DataFetcher()
    @State private var isPresentedEvent = false
    @State private var eventName: String = ""
    @State private var eventDescription: String = ""
    @State private var selectedStartTime = Date()
    @State private var selectedEndTime = Date()
    @State private var startTimeStamp: String = ""
    @State private var endTimeStamp: String = ""
    @Binding var annotationSelected: Bool
    var dateFormatter: DateFormatter {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateStyle = .full
        return formatter
    }



    func send(_ sender: Any) {

        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: NSURL(string: "http://localhost:5000/")! as URL)
            request.httpMethod = "POST"

        self.startTimeStamp = "\(self.selectedStartTime)"
        self.endTimeStamp = "\(self.selectedEndTime)"

        self.startTimeStamp.removeLast(5)
        self.endTimeStamp.removeLast(5)

        let postString = "b=\(self.eventName)&c=\(self.eventDescription)&d=\(self.startTimeStamp)&e=\(self.endTimeStamp)"

            request.httpBody = postString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)

            let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) {
                data, response, error in

                if error != nil {
                    print("error=\(String(describing: error))")
                    return
                }

                print("response = \(String(describing: response))")

                let responseString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
                print("responseString = \(String(describing: responseString))")
            }
            task.resume()

            self.eventName = ""
            self.eventDescription = ""
            self.selectedStartTime = Date()
            self.selectedEndTime = Date()

        }



    var body: some View {
        //UNCOMMENT THIS STUFF BELOW TO MAKE AN EVENT CREATION BUTTON IN THE SHEET INSTEAD OF JUST DIRECTING TO A SHEET WITH THE EVENT CREATION DETAILS
      Button(action: {
            self.isPresentedEvent.toggle() //trigger modal presentation
        }, label: {
            Text("Create Event").font(.system(size: 18)).foregroundColor(Color(.darkGray)).shadow(radius: 8)
            }).padding(EdgeInsets(top: 8, leading: 6, bottom: 8, trailing: 6))
                .foregroundColor(.secondary)
                .background(Color(.secondarySystemBackground))
                .cornerRadius(50.0)
                .sheet(isPresented: $isPresentedEvent, content:{
            VStack{
                TextField("Event Name", text: self.$eventName).padding()
                TextField("Event Description", text: self.$eventDescription).padding()
                Form {
                    DatePicker("When your event starts: ", selection: self.$selectedStartTime, in: Date()...)
                }
                Form {
                    DatePicker("When your event ends:   ", selection: self.$selectedEndTime, in: Date()...)
                }
                HStack{
                Button(action: {
                    self.isPresentedEvent.toggle()
                    self.annotationSelected = false
                    print("Start: \(self.selectedStartTime)")
                    print("End: \(self.selectedEndTime)")
                    self.send((Any).self)
                    }, label: {
                        Text("Create Event")
                    })
                Button(action: {
                    self.isPresentedEvent.toggle()
                    self.request.fetchEvents()
                    print("yo yo \(self.request.events.last?.address)")
                   }, label: {
                       Text("Cancel")
                   })
                }
                Text("Create Event Button (Non Functional)").padding()
            }
        } )
     }
}
```

Any insight on where I might be going wrong is much appreciated

Comment: Don't create the instance of `DataFetcher` in the view. You will keep getting new instances since views are immutable. You should create the instance and inject it into the view from the previous view or your scenedelegate if this is the top level view.

Comment: @Paulw11 I have passed an instance of dataFetcher in from my content view and the same problem persists. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Nothing in your view is bound to `self,request,events`.  The "yo yo..." print won't show an event because it executes before the asynchronous fetch is complete.

Comment: @Paulw11 is there a way I can execute after the asynchronous fetch is complete? I just want to be able to save and use the data that comes back from that function.

Comment: You say you want to "save and use the data" but you don't use the datain the view. With SwiftUI you need to have a clear understanding of the difference between your model and your view. Once the data is fetched in your model object you can use it in views. Since your `events` property is `@Published` you can bind a view to that property and the view will update once the data is fetched. You have no binding in the view you have shown so nothing happens once the data is fetched.

Comment: @Paulw11 how would you go about doing this in this code? Would I need to add to my content view or can what you're suggesting all be done in the files I've posted.

Answer (score 0):

```
                Button(action: {
                    self.isPresentedEvent.toggle()
                    self.request.fetchEvents()
                   }, label: {
                       if self.request.events.count > 0 {
                         Text("hey we have requests!")
                       } else {
                         Text("Cancel")
                       }
                   })
```

woops posted the accidently before finishing. one sec.

I believe it's a timing issue. The view is rendered before your request finishes fetching your data. You can add an if statement like above to update your view once the data is fully fetched.

Comment: I believe you're right in saying that the view is rendered before your request finishes fetching but your solution did not fix the problem